# Filter a list of list based on data

Tags: apl, dyalog

I've this data

```
      x ← ((1 'data1') (0 'data2') (0 'data3') (1 'data4') )
      x
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│┌─┬─────┐│┌─┬─────┐│┌─┬─────┐│┌─┬─────┐│
││1│data1│││0│data2│││0│data3│││1│data4││
│└─┴─────┘│└─┴─────┘│└─┴─────┘│└─┴─────┘│
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

I would like to filter the array like this

```
┌─────────┬─────────┐
│┌─┬─────┐│┌─┬─────┐│
││1│data1│││1│data4││
│└─┴─────┘│└─┴─────┘│
└─────────┴─────────┘
```

How can I achieve this?

I've tried this but it didn't work, it takes in account the first element only.

```
      ((⊃y)[1])/y←x
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│┌─┬─────┐│┌─┬─────┐│┌─┬─────┐│┌─┬─────┐│
││1│data1│││0│data2│││0│data3│││1│data4││
│└─┴─────┘│└─┴─────┘│└─┴─────┘│└─┴─────┘│
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news is that you got it almost right. Not bad for your first day of APL!

This minimal change to your code will do the trick:

```
      ((⊃¨y)=1)/y←x
┌─────────┬─────────┐
│┌─┬─────┐│┌─┬─────┐│
││1│data1│││1│data4││
│└─┴─────┘│└─┴─────┘│
└─────────┴─────────┘
```

However, there's no need to make a copy of `x` into `y`, since APL is normally pass-by-value. Furthermore, `=` is commutative, so we can get rid of the inner parenthesis:

```
      (1=⊃¨x)/x
┌─────────┬─────────┐
│┌─┬─────┐│┌─┬─────┐│
││1│data1│││1│data4││
│└─┴─────┘│└─┴─────┘│
└─────────┴─────────┘
```

You can then assign this to `y`:

```
      y← (1=⊃¨x)/x
      y
┌─────────┬─────────┐
│┌─┬─────┐│┌─┬─────┐│
││1│data1│││1│data4││
│└─┴─────┘│└─┴─────┘│
└─────────┴─────────┘
```

In fact, we can get rid of the outer parenthesis too, by explicitly commuting `/`:

```
      x/⍨1=⊃¨x
┌─────────┬─────────┐
│┌─┬─────┐│┌─┬─────┐│
││1│data1│││1│data4││
│└─┴─────┘│└─┴─────┘│
└─────────┴─────────┘
```

Alternatively, we can make `y` a copy of `x` and then filter `y` in-place:

```
      y/⍨←1=⊃¨y←x
      y
┌─────────┬─────────┐
│┌─┬─────┐│┌─┬─────┐│
││1│data1│││1│data4││
│└─┴─────┘│└─┴─────┘│
└─────────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: Amazing :D

I didn't know the glyph `⍨` 

Thanks so much for all these details ^^

Maybe I'will achieve the first day of AoC thanks to you :D

Comment: @YannickGuern No worries. Please continue to post questions. Know that you're always welcome in the https://apl.chat room.