# Apply a list of functions on the same right operand

Tags: apl, dyalog

I have 3 functions which return

```
parse_apple 1 'bpple4578'
┌─┬─────────┐
│0│bpple4578│
└─┴─────────┘
```

```
parse_bpple 1 'bpple4578'
┌─┬────┐
│1│4578│
└─┴────┘
```

```
parse_45 1 'bpple4578'
┌─┬─────────┐
│0│bpple4578│
└─┴─────────┘
```

I would like to apply this list of functions on 'bpple4578'

And return as soon as the first element of the result equals `1`.

So I've tried this:

```
⍝ Found somewhere in internet
split ← ⊢⊂⍨(⍴⊢)⍴1↑⍨⊣
test ← { (parse_apple, parse_45, parse_bpple) ¨(⊂⍵)}
data ← test 1 'bpple4578'
results ← 2 split ⊃data
⍝https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77594685/filter-a-list-of-list-based-on-data/77594809#77594809
x ← results/⍨1=⊃¨results
⎕ ← ⊃x
```

Is there a better way which get rid of the split function and the ravel glyph?